# Await for method to complete before moving on in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a question, i need to know how to wait for method completion before moving on.

I have a call by http get, in component:

```
private minTimestamp: Date;
private maxTimestamp: Date;

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getTimestamps();
 const filters: EventFilters = this.getFilters();
 this.dtOptions = this.eventsService.GetEvents(filters);
}

private getFilters(): EventFilters {
    console.log(this.selectedStartDate);
    console.log(this.selectedStartTime);
    return { FromTimestamp: new Date(`${this.selectedStartDate} ${this.selectedStartTime}`).toISOString(), ToTimestamp: new Date(`${this.selectedEndDate} ${this.selectedEndTime}`).toISOString()};
}

private getTimestamps() {
    this.eventsService.GetMinMaxTimestamp()
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.srcChannels = result;
          console.log('Src channels loaded');
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
          this.toastr.error('Fetching source channels filter failed');
        }
      );
  }
```

In service:

```
public GetMinMaxTimestamp(): Observable<TimestampBoundaries> {
    return this.http.get<TimestampBoundaries>(`${this.endpointsBaseUrl}GetMinMaxTimestamp`);
}
```

And now problem is GetEvents uses those dates, and getTimestamps completes later then get event gets fired and values are undefined. Is there a way?

Comment: It's not obvious why getEvents needs getTimestamps. GetEvents requires filters not timestamps. Please share more code. But this seems like a common `switchMap` case

Comment: try to use `async` and `await` like this `async asyncMethod() {
    const data1$ = await this.method1();
    const data2$ = await this.method2();
  }` this way it will call line by line to get data. assume that `method1()` and `method2()` will return observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need time stamps, to getEvents because according to your code, you need filters for getEvents and not time stamps. But still if you need to call it after you get timestamps, here is the solution.

The solution is to call getEvents after your getTimeStamps is completed, instead of calling it onInit.

```
private minTimestamp: Date;
private maxTimestamp: Date;

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getTimestamps();
}

private getFilters(): EventFilters {
    console.log(this.selectedStartDate);
    console.log(this.selectedStartTime);
    return { FromTimestamp: new Date(`${this.selectedStartDate} ${this.selectedStartTime}`).toISOString(), ToTimestamp: new Date(`${this.selectedEndDate} ${this.selectedEndTime}`).toISOString()};
}

private getTimestamps() {
    this.eventsService.GetMinMaxTimestamp()
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.srcChannels = result;
          console.log('Src channels loaded');
          const filters: EventFilters = this.getFilters();
          this.dtOptions = this.eventsService.GetEvents(filters);
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
          this.toastr.error('Fetching source channels filter failed');
        }
      );
  }
```

So basically, you get your filters and call getEvents after you get your time stamps

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Well this would work on a short term, but what if I would add additional filter that calls different api method.

Comment: Your filters do not come from any service call. So basically if you call it before getTimeStamps onInit, you will still have them. The main objective here is to call getEvents after getting timestamps based on your question. If you want filters onInit, just call getFilters before getTimeStamps.